# php curl: I need a simple post request and retrival of page example

Tags: php, curl

I would like to know how to send a post request in curl and get the response page.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://www.example.com/yourscript.php",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
        'field1' => 'some date',
        'field2' => 'some other data',
    )
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// result sent by the remote server is in $result
```

For a list of options that can be used with curl, you can take a look at the page of [`curl_setopt`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Here, you'll have to use, at least :

- `CURLOPT_POST` : as you want to send a POST request, and not a GET
- `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` : depending on whether you want `curl_exec` to return the result of the request, or to just output it.
- `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` : The data that will be posted -- can be written directly as a string, like a querystring, or using an array

And don't hesitate to read the [curl section](http://www.php.net/curl) of the PHP manual ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'username' => 'foo',
    'password' => 'bar'
);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the request to post using `CURLOPT_POST` and if you want to pass data with it, use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$data = array(
    'username' => 'foo',
    'password' => 'bar'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$contents = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Isn't CURLOPT_POST the count of data being passed? You make it sound like its a boolean

Answer (score 2):

try the one in the comments: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

(but add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1) to make it a post instead of get)

or this example: http://php.dzone.com/news/execute-http-post-using-php-cu

Answer (score 2):

```
  <?php
  ob_start();
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://example.com/student_list.php');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  echo $response;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add

```
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON DATA with CURL

client.php

```
    <?php 

$url="http://192.168.44.10/project/server/curl_server.php";
$data=['username'=>'abc','password'=>'123'];
$data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Content-Type: application/json'),
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $data
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;  //here you get result like: username: abc and password: 123
?>
```

curl_server.php

```
    <?php

    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $Data= json_decode($data,true);

    echo 'username: '.$Data['username']." and password: ".$Data['password'];
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out my code in this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56027033/6733212

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('curl_version')) {
    exit("Enable cURL in PHP");
}

$url = "https://www.google.com/";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Accept: */*",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Connection: keep-alive",
        "Host: " . url($url),
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36",
        "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
    ),
));

function url($url)
{
    $result = parse_url($url);
    return $result['host'];
}
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo "<textarea>" . $response . "</textarea>";

}
```

http://codepad.org/YE6fyzCA