# Send data via PHP CURL?

Tags: php, curl, dashing

I'm trying to send some data to Dashing which is a dashboard application. To do this you have to CURL for example.

```
url -d '{ "auth_token": "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN", "text": "Hey, Look what I can do!" }' \http://127.0.0.1:3030/widgets/welcome
```

This will update the widget,

I'm just wondering how to do effectively this via PHP?

This is what I have now

```
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3030/widgets/welcome';
$fields = array(
            'auth_token' => "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN",
            'text' => "ssssssssssss"
        );
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

This doesn't work, how would I sent this string?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I submit POST data using PHP and cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968857/how-do-i-submit-post-data-using-php-and-curl)

Comment: to error check use `curl_error($ch) `

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Need more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post JSON to PHP with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813487/how-to-post-json-to-php-with-curl)