# How can I get past the login page to capture a page using biterScripting?

Tags: web-scraping

The website (https) I want to copy requires username and password to access the website. I tried Biterscripting, but it only copies the login page and not the actual web page. I am not sure if there is a way to input the username and password using a script.

"http:// username:password @ address" still gives me the login page and not the actual web page.

Given a list of URLs, I want to copy the contents to text files.

Comment: What's "Biterscripting"?    What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: I don't have a language in particular. I am searching for some program that can access and copy web pages that first require going through a login page. Step by step instructions would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use biterscripting commands for IS (Internet Session) like this. (To POST to a page, you need to use the 'ispost' command. To GET a page, you can just use the 'cat' command.)

```
# Declare variables
var str page

# Start internet session, named s, user agent Mozilla.
isstart s "" "Mozilla/5.0"

# If the site is https://www.abc.def, connect to site.
isconnect s "https://www.abc.def" > $page

# The site's index page is in variable $page.
# Suppose the login form is in this format -

# <form name="login" action="login.php" method="post">
# Account: <input type="text" name="login"><
# Password: <input type="password" name="pswd">
# <input type="submit" value="submit">
# </form>

# Login by posting "login=me&pswd=mypassword&submit=submit" to login.php.
ispost s "login.php" "login=me&pswd=mypassword&submit=submit" > $page
# "me" and "mypassword" are values of login and password.
```

The page after the login is now in variable $page. I thought this is the page you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What language do you use?

First you have to login, and then retrieve the result page.

You can use cURL to achieve this. Here you have a simple example using cURL with PHP:

[php curl: I need a simple post request and retrival of page example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440252/php-curl-i-need-a-simple-post-request-and-retrival-of-page-example)