# How can I make this api post request in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, rest, api

I made a post request for an api using ajax. I wonder how I can do the same in php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var cbIntegrationId = "xxxxxx"; // I have it
  var clientId = "xxxxxxx"; //I have it
  var clientSecret = "xxxxx"; //I have it
  var tableName = "Test_Database";

    //Get access token
    $.post(
      "https://" + cbIntegrationId + ".caspio.com/oauth/token",
      {
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret
      },
      function(cbAuth){
        //Run POST call
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://" + cbIntegrationId + ".caspio.com/rest/v2/tables/" + tableName + "/records?response=rows",
          type: 'POST',
          'data': JSON.stringify({"UniqueID":"988"}), //Define record values
          headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + cbAuth.access_token, //Extracts the access token from the initial authorization call
            "Content-Type": "application/json", //Required, otherwise 415 error is returned
            "Accept": "application/json"
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.Result); //Check the console to view the new added row
          },
          error: function(data) {
            console.log(data.responseJSON); //Check the console to view error message if any
          }
        });
      }
    );
</script>
```

I did some research but couldn't find anything that would solve my problem. I really need your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

Comment: What is the problem that you are having, any errors or the unexpected behaviour should be part of your question to help others see what is going wrong.

Comment: try http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/curl) to call an API using PHP.

So according to your case you are sending data using POST method. So, we can use cURL as follows with some headers,

```
$apiURL = "https://yourURL";
$uniqueID = "UniqueID:988";
$postData = json_encode($uniqueID); // Encode the data into a JSON string
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer " . $token; // Prepare the authorization token

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authorization, 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept : application/json')); // Inject the token into the header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // To get actual result from the successful operation
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1); // Specify HTTP protocol version to use;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Specify the request method as POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $apiURL); // Pass the API URL
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); // Set the posted fields
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // This will follow any redirects

$response = curl_exec($curl); // Here you will get the response after executing
$error = curl_error($curl); // Return a string containing the last error for the current session

curl_close($curl); // Close a cURL session
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: and i get this message `Bad request`

Comment: thank you @Hasitha M Jayawardana. It works. I had failed the url

Comment: Pleased to know it helped :)

Comment: Hello @Hasitha M Jayawardana. Today I want to edit some fields. How can i do that? I tried to edit the code that you sent me and it didnt work

Comment: @AmílcarPaco What fields? I suggest you can open a new thread to that if you have another issue.

Comment: Stackoverflow  no longer accepting questions from my account. Please see this link  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NPmM-HxPz6BjE4yieYV9REPNkLyZdaeq  you may open a new thread and send us a link. Thank you

Comment: @AmílcarPaco Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440252/php-curl-i-need-a-simple-post-request-and-retrival-of-page-example) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)